# Saving text to zip file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, zip

I have some problems with a Javascript zip lib. We are using the following lin in our project: https://github.com/nodeca/pako

Now I try the following zip a text from a string and put it iin a blob, so that the user may download it to disk. Sounds pretty simple but just do not get around it

```
        binaryString = Zip.deflate(text, {to:'string'});
        blob = new Blob([binaryString], {type:'application/zip'});

        if(window.webkitURL) { // Chrome
            window.open(window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob));
        } else {
            window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        }
```

Has somebody an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: a zip file is more than just a stream of deflated text. you're telling the browser you're giving it a zip file, but you're not, you are just giving it a blob of compressed data with no file times, folder listing, etc. btw, the correct mime type is "x-application/zip". look into jszip, it makes downloadable files. also, forgiving apps like 7zip MIGHT be able to unpack the invalid "zip" file the above code produces, if that's enough for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks. You are wright, my probelm is that 7zip for example can not deflate the file, that is saved. Do you have an idea how to create a file with this lib? I have to use since it is the one that is defined to be used in our project. Or do I need another lib?

Comment: you would have to inflate() the result in JS yourself instead of using an application.